# How to tell if a MySQL database is being accessed?

Tags: mysql

Is there some convenient way to see which users are accessing a MySQL database?  Ideally I'd have some kind of application making this easy, but other methods would be OK.

If there isn't a standard definition, I would accept "have queried the database in the last 30 minutes".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about the query:

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST
```

This will show you connections to the database, what user they are logged in with, the state of the connection, and any currently running command.

Comment: Great.  I've created a user with only select_priv and a script that uses that user to run that command so I can parse it to see if it's the only user in the result.  This should work! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

From the command line (assuming you have a .my.cnf folder in your home directory),

```
echo Total\ Connections:; mysqladmin processlist | tail -n +4 | head -n -1 | grep Sleep | wc -l ; echo ; echo Current\ Users: ; mysqladmin processlist | tail -n +4 | head -n -1 | grep Sleep | awk '{print $4}' | sort | uniq
```

This gives a nice printout of unique users and total connections.

Comment: This server is actually Windows 2003, but +1 for a comprehensive one-line solution.  (Maybe I'll get to use it on one of my Linux boxen...?)